# Resampling and interpolation of pandas dataframe with multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks roughly like this:

| timestamp | mmsi | departures_count | calc_speed | coursechange |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2012-01-31 07:11:59 | 1.252340e+12 | 1 | 4.041755 | 0.000000 |
| 2012-01-31 07:22:20 | 1.252340e+12 | 1 | 5.209561 | 30.000000 |
| 2012-01-31 07:35:34 | 1.252340e+12 | 2 | 5.766184 | 1.000000 |
| 2012-01-31 07:45:35 | 1.252340e+12 | 2 | 5.932638 | 4.000000 |
| 2016-11-24 17:05:21 | 2.775153e+14 | 1 | 1.673716 | 17.000000 |
| 2016-11-24 17:21:21 | 2.775153e+14 | 1 | 0.725156 | 180.800003 |
| 2016-11-24 17:38:40 | 2.775153e+14 | 1 | 0.418093 | 117.500003 |

The Dataframe has more columns and way more rows (2284331 rows x 16 columns), but these are the important ones needed for the operations.

It consists of unique identifiers *mmsi* and *departures_count* indicating an associated trip. Since the timestep between datapoints varies significantly, I am trying to resample the data for better comparison. I would like the timesteps to always be 10 minutes. This means that I want to upsample the data if there are multiple datapoints within a 10 minute span und downsample it (using interpolation) when there is a larger timegap. This needs to be done for each *departures_count* per *mmsi*.

I tried using the following but it either just returns NaN's or the same value for each row of a trip (departure).

```
timeindex = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.index = timeindex
group = df.groupby(['mmsi', 'departures_count'])
df_test = group[['coursechange', 'calc_speed']].resample('10Min').interpolate(method='linear')
```

If possible, I would also like to change the interpolation method to cubic instead of linear.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
def fn(g):
    rng = pd.date_range(
        g.index[0].floor("10min"), g.index[-1].ceil("10min"), freq="10min"
    )
    g = (
        g.reindex(g.index.union(rng))
        .interpolate(method="linear", limit_direction="both")
        .reindex(rng)
    )
    return g


df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df = df.set_index("timestamp")

out = df.groupby(["mmsi", "departures_count"], group_keys=False).apply(fn)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
                             mmsi  departures_count  calc_speed  coursechange
2012-01-31 07:10:00  1.252340e+12               1.0    4.041755      0.000000
2012-01-31 07:20:00  1.252340e+12               1.0    4.625658     15.000000
2012-01-31 07:30:00  1.252340e+12               1.0    5.209561     30.000000
2012-01-31 07:30:00  1.252340e+12               2.0    5.766184      1.000000
2012-01-31 07:40:00  1.252340e+12               2.0    5.849411      2.500000
2012-01-31 07:50:00  1.252340e+12               2.0    5.932638      4.000000
2016-11-24 17:00:00  2.775153e+14               1.0    1.673716     17.000000
2016-11-24 17:10:00  2.775153e+14               1.0    1.357529     71.600001
2016-11-24 17:20:00  2.775153e+14               1.0    1.041343    126.200002
2016-11-24 17:30:00  2.775153e+14               1.0    0.571624    149.150003
2016-11-24 17:40:00  2.775153e+14               1.0    0.418093    117.500003
```